# Why is "mysql_connect" discouraged and what are the alternatives?

Tags: php, mysql, wamp, deprecated

I'm trying to learn about database management and MySQL through PHP. The problem is [all](http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/PHP_and_MySQL_Tutorial_-_Lesson_2) [the](http://zetcode.com/databases/mysqlphptutorial/) [tutorials](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlconnection.php) I've seen use `mysql_connect` and according to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php) that's bad. What is the problem with using `mysql_*` functions and what are the alternatives? If there are any free online tutorial please post the link.

Comment: A much used comment by some users contains some helpful links - Avoid using the dated mysql_* functions. Using them for new code is highly
[discouraged](http://php.net/mysql_query).
More modern alternatives are available and better maintained.
Consider learning about
[prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)
instead and use either
[PDO or MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).
When used strictly they avoid the tedious and manual escaping part,
thus become heaps easier and as by-product safer to use.
See [a PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: And then, in general, the procedural paradigm it's discouraged, try to approach the Object Oriented Paradigm.

Comment: @Fabio why is OOP better than procedural paradigm?

Comment: PDO thats why. yes there is mysqli, but PDO is pretty safe when running queries and it can actually make things easier.

Comment: @Celeritas Not that OOP is better, but it does a lot of work for you. You can then carry that object throughout your script without having to redefine something or redo something, thus adding more code.

Comment: But the question is asking *why* and now I'm kind of curious too.  Certainly prepared statements are safer, but is that the only reason?  Not much help in the faq (http://us.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) either.

Comment: @Aerik they also changed it to an object. But they probably just aren't going to support it anymore.

Comment: @Celeritas: the answer requires more than a comment :-) Start here, however: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/67717/procedural-code-vs-oop-code

Answer (score 5):

You can try using `mysqli` the `i` stands for *Improved* to access to your Database and it offers a lot more functions than just the `mysql` connector, or also you can use `PDO` wich stands for *PHP Data Objects* which is the one i prefer because it will let you use more than just *MySQL* as a database.

[PDO Link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)  
[mysqli Link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)