# Writing to online mysql database

Tags: php, android, mysql, database

In an online tutorial, I found a way how to write to a mysql online database.

Here is my php part:

```
<?php
echo 'test';
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","user","pwd","dbname");

if(mysql_connect_errno($connect))
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_connect_error();
}
else
{
    echo "success";
}

$name= isset($_POST['appname']) ? $_POST['appname'] : '';
$email= isset($_POST['appemail']) ? $_POST['appemail'] : '';

$query = mysql_query($connect, "insert into jagdenwilli(name, email) values ('$name' ,'$email') ");

mysql_close($connect);
?>
```

`user` and `pwd` normally are the username and password for my mysql database, `dbname` is the name of my database (id,name,email,date)

Here is my android part:

```
public void senden(){
    Toast t = Toast.makeText(this, "asd", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    t.show();

    String name = "Herbert";
    String email = "herbert@gmail.com";
    HttpClient httpclient;
    HttpPost httppost;
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;


            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.ff-ehrnsdorf.at/jagdenwilli.php");

            try
            {
                nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));

                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

I'm sure that the link I access is the right one but I don´t get any data in my database. There are also no errors. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Did you read from the `response` object? On my test, it says `testUnable to select database` ....!? Check your database connection parameters.

Comment: Sorry I'm new in the database thing... how can I read from it?

Comment: @user896692 I updated my answer again, it has a sample mysql connection example. Take a look and try to plug in the correct values for you setup.

Comment: @user896692 - 1) You should start using mySqli or PDO interfaces instead of the old - deprecated - "mysql_connect" and friends:[Why is mysql_connect discouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679033/why-is-mysql-connect-discouraged-and-what-are-the-alternatives). 2) You should use [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).  3) You should become familiar with your server's access and error logs.  IMHO...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like your variable names do not match up:

`name` & `email` on the Java side

vs `appname` and `appemail` in your request param lookup on the PHP side

Match them up and you should be good to go.

Also for your connect statement: use this syntax:

```
$handle = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
```

A simple example mysql configuration is below:

```
$h = "127.0.0.1"; 
$u = "root"; 
$p = ""; 
$database = "gps";

$handle = mysql_connect($h, $u, $p);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");
if (!$handle) {
    echo "Could not connect to server\n";
    trigger_error(mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

In your case you'd just need to replace $u & $p with your username and password. You'd also need to replace $database with the name of the database/schema that your table is located in.

Comment: Have you checked your php looks to see if the request is even triggering the code? Also if you manually navigate to the URL and pass in values for it, does it insert?

Comment: How can I look if is triggering the code? Ok I tried to give values over the URL but still no success...

Comment: Ok with your edited answer, I get 'Unable to select database'.. What value should $database have?

Comment: It should be the name of the mysql schema where your table `jagdenwilli` lives. <schema>.jagdenwilli

Comment: At some point you would have typed `use <schema>` and then created your table `jagdenwilli`. Whatever schema your table is located is the value you need to plugin for $dbname

Comment: Thanks for updating again but I still don´t get a connection. "Unable to select database"...

Comment: Is there a way to show an error log on the server? Maybe then I can find the error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44521/discussion-between-magicman-and-user896692)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use "mysql_query()".

Instead, you should absolutely use prepared statements, and an API like PDO or MySQLi instead:

https://www.php.net/pdo.prepared-statements

https://www.php.net/mysqli_query

```
<?php
// EXAMPLE:
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);

// insert one row
$name = 'one';
$value = 1;
$stmt->execute();
```

Also, per MagicMan, make sure the arguments in your form match the variable names in your PHP, and the column names in your insert match the column names in your database.

Comment: Also: 1) Check the access and error logs on your server, 2) Look at this link: [PHP MySqlii insert not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811070/php-mysqli-insert-not-working-no-errors)